# Background Image not working in IE8 in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I have this simple HTML DIV with background, where Image is not showing up in IE8. It's working on all other browsers.

I am using AngularJS by the way.

The div is:-

```
<div class="slide" 
     style="background-image:url(content/1.jpg); 
            background-repeat:no-repeat; min-width:955px; 
            min-height:420px; display:block;"> 
</div>
```

Thanks.

### EDIT

I just checked and in IE the background is not there to begin with.

The tag in IE is being shown as :-

```
<div class="slide" style="min-width: 955px; min-height: 420px; display: block; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Weird.

Comment: Have you got a live link/dev area we can test this?

Comment: I just pasted your code and it worked for me in IE8

Comment: Works in IE8 for me as well. I think this might be something else. Can you put together a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I am using Angular JS, probably this is something about it?

Comment: Did you try using quotes around the image link? IE8 might be sensitive to those things

Comment: Yes sir you are right. May be you can write this as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: @Steve I answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on Internet Explorer, but I do know that browsers in the past were not as flexible on rules as the updated browsers today. Technically, `background-image` is supposed to have quotes wrapping the image. So try adding those in, and see if it works.

```
background-image:url("content/1.jpg");
```

As a side note, you could condense the `background-image` and `background-repeat` into one rule. It would look like this.

```
background: url("content/1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

And just in case you can't get it to work, you should always include a background color for the cases when the image can't load.

```
background-color: white;
/* Or */
background: white url("content/1.jpg") no-repeat;
```